# Drupal: views taxonomies tree

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I am working with taxonomies and nodes and I want to show them in a view.

My taxonomies are:

Product Category
- Product Line
-- Product
--- Features (Node)

I want to show this tree in a view but I can not get a good result.

For example I have:

Product category (phones)
- Product line (phone a)
-- Product (phone 104)
- Product line (phone b)
-- Product (phone 202)
- Product line (phone a)
-- Product (phone 124)
- Product line (phone b)
-- Product (phone 242)

And I want this result:

> phones
>   phone a
>   phone 104
>   phone 124
>   phone b
>   phone 202
>   phone 242

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the api function [taxonomy_get_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7)

With his function you can get your tanonomy structure. Then you can make a custom template.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://drupal.org/project/views_tree.

There is Drupal 6 version available. 
In case of Drupal 7 version, check the issue http://drupal.org/node/1044362.